# Disprove that x-hat is extremal

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I'm new to optimization and I found this problem: Disprove the statement: Give the polyhedron $P=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax-By \ge b, y\le 1$}. The point $\hat{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is extremal if and only if $\hat{x}$ is a feasible point in $P$. How would I begin to disprove this? If anyone knows what x-hat thing means it would also be very helpful. Thanks to anyone for the help!!
Edit:
Definition:
Let P be a polyhedron. z ∈ rec(P) \ {0} is called an extremal of P if cone{z} is an extremal ray of rec(P).

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What definition are you using for extremal point?

Comment: I put the definition in the post

Comment: I doesn't seem a difficult problem becasue to disprove that you only need an example in which the result doen't hold. Thanks for clarifiy the definition of extremal, but I when I was trying to find an example I realized that you didn't define y and b. Also the hat represent an arbitrary point $x$ that satisfy the property (used to distinguish it from other $x$).

Comment: Please also provide the definition of a polyhedron, since it is all but [unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Definition). Also, I'm not sure what the statement is supposed to be. Is it "For all $A$, $B$, $b$ a point is extremal for $P$ iff it is feasible." or is it "A point is extremal for $P$ iff it is feasible", where $A$, $B$, $b$ are some given values? If it is the latter, please provide $A$, $B$, $b$, otherwise please at least specify the dimensions. It's also confusing because $P$ is not necessarily bounded. And if a polyhedron is 3D, then $n$ should be $3$. Thanks!

Comment: But this is all of the info that I have?

Comment: By the way, that $\hat x$-thing is just any point $\mathbb R^n$. You could replace $\hat x$ by $y$ everywhere in your post, and it wouldn't change anything, mathematically speaking.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just point out a few facts.

Let $A=B\equiv 0$ and $b>0$, then $P=\emptyset$. In this case, if the emptyset is a polyhedron, then the sets of extremal points and feasible points coincide.

Now, let $a_i\in\mathbb R^{n+1}$ be given by $a_{i,1}=1$, $a_{i,i}=-1$ and $a_{i,j}=0$ otherwise, for $2\le i\le n+1$. Let $A=(a_{i+1,j})_{i,j}\in\mathbb R^{n+1\times n}$. For $x\in\mathbb R^n$ let $y=Ax=\sum_ix_ia_{i+1}$. Notice that if there exists $i$ with $x_i>0$, then we have $y_i<0$. Otherwise, if there exists $i$ with $x_i<0$, then we have $y_1=\sum_jx_j\le x_i<0$ because $x\le 0$. So we have $y\ge 0$ if and only if $y=0$, which we have if and only if $x=0$. So, for $B\equiv 0$ and $b\equiv 0$ we have $P=\{0\}$, which is also both the set of extremal points and feasible points, using the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) definition.

These are two examples where the statement is true, depending on the definitions. Now, we turn to an example where the statement is false.
For this purpose take $A$ from above, let $B\equiv 0$ and $b\equiv -1/(n+1)$.
Let $e_i$ be the $i$-th unit vector in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. By construction, the set $Q=\{Ax:x\in P\}$ is the [standard simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) shifted by $b$. Hence, $P$ is the convex hull of the $n$ unique corners $c_i$ given by $Ac_i=e_i+b$. The map $A:P\rightarrow Q$ is clearly a bijection that preserves feasible points and extreme points, and $0\in Q$ is clearly feasible but not extremal.

Hence, we have seen two cases where the statement holds and one where it doesn't. In general, it's not hard to see that the extremal points and the feasible points of a (general) polytope $P$ coincide if and only if $P$ has at most one point. Because, if $P$ has at least two points, take any two, consider the connecting line using that polytopes are convex, and notice that any point on this line is feasible and not extremal.